# Dynamic Pivot Table syntax error

Tags: mysql, pivot, concat, group-concatenation

What's wrong with this Dynamic Pivot table query? I'm staring myself blind on this.

```
mysql> SET @sql = NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    ->     CONCAT(
    ->       'IF(q.label = ''',
    ->       label,
    ->       ''', 1, 2) AS ',
    ->       label
    ->    )
    ->   ) INTO @sql
    -> FROM question;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT a.id, ', @sql, ', q.id
    '>       FROM answer a
    '>       INNER JOIN question q ON questionId = q.id
    '>       GROUP BY a.id');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near ' q.id
```

Why does the first one pass but the second one blows up?

Adding `PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;` on the `GROUP_CONCAT` query gives me this:

```
You have an error ... near 'IF(q.label = 'Q1', 1, 2) AS Q1,IF(q.label = 'Q2', 1, 2) AS Q2,IF(q.label = '', 1' at line 1
```

I'm not expecting the label to be empty on the last if, but I don't see how that would blow up the last query.

The query without the dynamic part returns this:

```
+----+-------+----+
| id | label | id |
+----+-------+----+
|  1 | Q1    |  1 |
|  2 | Q2    |  1 |
|  3 | Q1    |  1 |
|  4 | Q2    |  1 |
+----+-------+----+
```

Comment: Anytime you are working with Dynamic SQL, always have a debug line that shows the resulting SQL statement.

Comment: @MichaelKutz You mean add a `PREPARE stmt FROM @sql`; after the `GROUP_CONCAT` query? I've updated my question.

Comment: @MichaelKutz Yeah it was the null value that screwed it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct form of the if clause

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT(
       'IF(q.label = "',
       label,
       '", 1, 2) AS ',
       label
    )
   ) INTO @sql
    FROM question;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT a.id, ', @sql, ', q.id
       FROM answer a
       INNER JOIN question q ON questionId = q.id
       GROUP BY a.id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
```

But still you should always write the result of
    SET @sql = NULL;

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT(
       'IF(q.label = "',
       label,
       '", 1, 2) AS ',
       label
    )
   ) INTO @sql
    FROM question;
 SELECT @sql;
```

Comment: But the value of `@sql` is never null.

Comment: Could you please provide the data and not only the result of your or at least make a select @sql before you concat it.

Comment: Already updated the question. Turns out the problem was with `IF(q.label = ''...`

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: So double quotes to make the second query not blow up on null or empty `q.label` values?

Comment: Just tried that. Doesn't work either. Not really a problem as long as I ensure `q.label` is never null.

Comment: If you update your answer to reflect the null issue I will happily accept and upvote.